# overflow error in loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, overflow

I need some help, i received overflow error with my code and I cant figure out why.

basically, I want to delete a row if the data is matching with previous row.

the debug stopped at the c = c - 1

I make it to update the last row every loop in order to stop at the end of the table.

```
clastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ClaimData").Cells( _
                            claim.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For c = 3 To clastrow

    If claim.Range("A" & c).Value = claim.Range("A" & c - 1).Value And _
           claim.Range("E" & c).Value = claim.Range("E" & c - 1).Value Then

        claim.Range("K" & c - 1).Value = claim.Range("K" & c - 1).Value + _
                                         claim.Range("K" & c).Value
        claim.Rows(c).Delete
        a = c
        c = a - 1
        clastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ClaimData").Cells( _
                                  claim.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    End If
Next c
```

Comment: clastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ClaimData").Cells(claim.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For c = 3 To clastrow

If claim.Range("A" & c).Value = claim.Range("A" & c - 1).Value And claim.Range("E" & c).Value = claim.Range("E" & c - 1).Value Then
    claim.Range("K" & c - 1).Value = claim.Range("K" & c - 1).Value + claim.Range("K" & c).Value
        claim.Rows(c).Delete
        a = c
        c = a - 1
clastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ClaimData").Cells(claim.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
End If

Next c

Comment: The logic is much easier to manage if you work from the bottom up.

Comment: clastrow is **never** going to be redefined as fas as your For ... Next is concerned. Work from the bottom up.

Answer (score 0):

Work from the bottom up:

```
With claim

    clastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For c = clastrow To 3 Step -1

        If .Cells(c, "A").Value = .Cells(c - 1, "A").Value And _
           .Cells(c, "E").Value = .Cells(c - 1, "E").Value Then

            .Cells(c - 1, "K").Value = .Cells(c - 1, "K").Value + .Cells(c, "K").Value
            .Rows(c).Delete

        End If
    Next c

End With
```

Comment: Perfect. It works like magic. I am a newbie as you can tell, I haven't been coding for 10 years plus